# Printers do not recognize my USB 3.0 Disk drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, printer

I have tried all of my university printers and they do not manage to detect it. Is it normal? Should i ask for replacement? Its under warranty. I suppose it is a software issue since USB 2.0 can perfectly work with USB 3.0 or its my drive thats faulty. Works well on my laptop tho.

Comment: What filesystem is there on the USB drive? Can you tell if there is a partition table or the thing is a superfloppy?

Comment: Have you tried any other USB drive? How about trying a USB 2.0 drive? What filesystem does the printer expect? What model is it?

Comment: ooh partition can be a problem. ill check and reformat to ntfs